# Verifying 22.0-4 ISO Download Problem

Tags: 22.04, iso, sha256sum

How Do I Verify Ubuntu 22.04 ISO Download

I'm having issues installing Ubuntu 22.04 iso on an old PC. So I'm checking all the steps.
step 1 was to verify the iso file and I followed the steps suggested at
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview
The latter steps didn't seem to work.
ie
the command "gpg --keyid-format long --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg SHA256SUMS" produced the result:
gpg: can't open signed data 'SHA256SUMS'
gpg: can't hash datafile: No such file or directory

and also the command
"sha256sum -c SHA256SUMS 2>&1 | grep OK"
got no result.
I interpreted this as a bad checksum so I downloaded the iso file again and followed the same procedure. But got the same result.

Think I'll just have to try the install again.

Comment: Obviously, you do not have a file `SHA256SUMS` and/or `SHA256SUMS.gpg`. Read what the program is telling you. It says `gpg: can't open signed data 'SHA256SUMS' gpg: can't hash datafile: No such file or directory`. Did you follow the steps precisely?

Comment: you say an old PC - just how old and which architecture? [edit] in to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Following through the instructions that you are following, at Step 3 or page https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#3-download-checksums-and-signatures you will see

> However, if you didn’t, not to worry - the checksums and the signature
> are consistent for the image, so even if you downloaded your ISO file
> from a different source, as long as it is fresh and hasn’t been
> updated in the interim, you can fetch these files from the
> http://releases.ubuntu.com page for the relevant release.

From there you can download the `SHA256SUMS` and `SHA256SUMS.gpg` files.  I have also conveniently added them here for you:

```
wget http://releases.ubuntu.com/jammy/SHA256SUMS
wget http://releases.ubuntu.com/jammy/SHA256SUMS.gpg
```

Now when you run the command of `gpg --keyid-format long --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg SHA256SUMS` you will probably get something like the following with the missing key:

```
$ gpg --keyid-format long --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg SHA256SUMS
gpg: Signature made Thu 10 Aug 2023 12:33:07 PM MDT
gpg:                using RSA key 843938DF228D22F7B3742BC0D94AA3F0EFE21092
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
```

To import your key it is the command from `gpg` but remember to add `0x` to the beginning of the key since it is in hexadecimal format.

```
gpg --keyid-format long --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 0x843938DF228D22F7B3742BC0D94AA3F0EFE21092
```

Now your key check should pass:

```
gpg --keyid-format long --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg SHA256SUMS
gpg: Signature made Thu 10 Aug 2023 12:33:07 PM MDT
gpg:                using RSA key 843938DF228D22F7B3742BC0D94AA3F0EFE21092
gpg: BAD signature from "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) <cdimage@ubuntu.com>" [unknown]
```

Now when you run the `sha256sum` command it should verify if your downloaded ISO is OK or not:

```
$ sha256sum -c SHA256SUMS 2>&1 | grep OK
ubuntu-22.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso: OK
```